# Как избежать проблем с цикличными ссылками в таблицах БД?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

У меня есть `user` и есть `project`

1. `user` может иметь несколько `project` как `creator`
2. `project` может иметь 1 `user`, который `creator` и много других `user` как `contributors`

То есть тут наблюдается то, что `user` ссылается на `project`, а он в свою очередь обратно на `user` и Sequelize начинает ругаться на цикличные связи.

Как избежать такую проблему?

Вот код `sequelize-classes`

User model:

```
@hasMany('Project', { foreignKey: 'creatorId' })
export class User extends Model {
  id = {
    type: INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
}
```

Project model:

```
@hasMany('User', { foreignKey: 'contributor' })
export class Project extends Model {
  name = {
    type: STRING,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
      min: 2
    }
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: Cyclic dependency found. Users is dependent
>   of itself. Dependency chain: Users -> Projects => Users

Comment: Здесь нет цикличных ссылок. user может не иметь ни одного project. С архитектурой всё в порядке, изменений не требуется, почему у вас ошибки - хрен знает

Comment: @andreymal (node:19636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cyclic dependency found. Users is dependent of itself.
Dependency chain: Users -> Projects => Users

Comment: Не вижу цикла, особенно если слова в ваших предложениях немного переставить. Ведь у вас только проекты ссылаются на пользователей, только двумя связями, одна по creator видимо из самой таблицы projects и вторая через связующую таблицу

Comment: @Herrgott с архитектурой всё в порядке, добавьте весь код связанный с ошибкой

Comment: Вы лучше поясните как вы изобразили первый пункт, что у вас пользователь ссылается на проекты ....

Comment: @mike обновил вопрос

Comment: @andreymal обновил

Comment: Не знаю что это за sequelize но если бы эта была бы обычная реляционная БД то у меня в таблице проектов была бы ссылка на users. Думаю что то типа hasOne('User', ...)

Comment: @Mike sequelize это орм для mysql, postgresql, mssql и пр.

Comment: Я наверное не правильно сформулировал вопрос

Comment: А чем вам hasOne('User') в классе Project не нравится ?

Comment: @Mike потому что юзер может иметь несколько контрибьюторов

Comment: А причем тут контрибутор. Мы говорим про creator. И мы ссылку не в юзера помещаем, а в проект. У проекта может быть только 1 создатель. Вот и пишем, _в проекте_, что у него один создатель. Что равноценно фразе "пользователь создал несколько проектов". А сейчас у вас выходит, что у пользователя есть поле creator, указывающее на проекты. т.е. проект создал пользователя ...

Comment: Т.е. с точки зрения БД я это так вижу http://clip2net.com/s/3O7tvNH теперь это надо выразить средствами sequelize ...